# UITextView - Empty space lines at the beginning after repositioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview

I am developing an app for iOS7. I have a UITextView, which is 38 high. I reposition the textview when the keyboard pops up using below code.

```
  self.textview.frame = CGRectMake(self.newTextView.frame.origin.x,
                                   self.newTextView.frame.origin.y,
                                   self.newTextView.frame.size.width,
                                   self.newTextView.frame.size.height);
```

However, then the cursor doesn't show at (0,0), instead it positions at (0, 63). I tried to fix it using below code.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible: [textView selectedRange]];
}
```

This helps to scroll to the cursor position when user starts typing. However, you could notice several non editable empty lines above the first sentence that user typed.

I want to remove these empty lines and set editable position at (0,0). Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the textView.text is not completely empty in the first place? Try setting it to `@""` when you load the view.

Comment: I initialized it. The text length is 0 after the view load. Cursor doesn't move into those lines even if press back/delete button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out. I set Content Top Inset through storyboard at -63. All is good now. Setting Content Inset through program didn't work though.